# Help identifying a plant with pink flowers

Tags: identification

It's a rose I bought 3 days ago, I think it really grows fast, it produce a new flower every 1-2 days!
[image]
[image]
BTW, is there something wrong with the flowers?

Comment: I don't think that's a rose. Someone will know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most definitely not a rose. As for what it is, I suspect it's [*Clarkia amoena*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkia_amoena), previously named Godetia. These come in various colours and bi colours, usually in the deep pink through to whitish pink range, and are annuals.

Comment: Mmm it may be a mistake in translation - thanks

Comment: @almousawi you're probably right - 'rose' often seems to be a generic term meaning 'flowering plant', I've noticed it before.